# 404.2 Error after installing .net 4.0

Tags: iis, .net-4.0

I have a project which I have upgraded to .Net 4.0, but when I try to access it, I retrieve the following error:

```
HTTP Error 404.2 - Not Found
The page you requested could not be displayed because of the settings for the list of ISAPI and CGI restrictions on web server.
ErrorCode: 0x800704ec
Handler PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit
```

Do I need to do something extra to the IIS 7 or APP pool, when converting an existing site to a .NET 4.0 site?

Also if I look at ISAPI both 32bit and 64bit of the .Net 4.0 is installed.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In IIS, enable .NET 4.

Here is image:
[image]

Comment: I have the .Net 4 installed in the IIS.

Comment: When I go to ISAPI in IIS 7 there is no column for me telling if it is allowed or not?

Comment: I found out that I had to look in the ISAPI & CGI limitations, and it wasn't enabled. I enabled it and it then worked. Thanks!

Comment: Bump! Worked for me, also had to set up the domain user permissions on the ASP.Net Temp folder.

Comment: If the image link doesn't display, ctrl+5 to refresh some reason it sometimes reports as being corrupted.

Comment: Here's the scripted version (be sure to modify to match which version you're after):
`"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config /section:isapiCgiRestriction /[path='%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4122\aspnet_isapi.dll'].allowed:True`

Answer (score 9):

I take it you're running on IIS6 right now..

Open the IIS manager, and go to the *Web Service Extensions* area.. You'll be able to enable .NET 4 in there.. All new extensions are disabled by default :)

If you're running on IIS7, .NET might not have registered in IIS.. Then open up an admin command prompt and navigate to the .NET 4 framework folder (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.{version}). If you're on a 64 bit machine go to the Framework64 folder instead of the Framework folder.
Then run `aspnet_regiis -i` in there

Comment: I have updated the post. I am using IIS 7, and I have tried aspnet_regiis -i, but still no difference. I have also changed the app pool to both v4 classic and v4 (regular) and still no difference.

Comment: I had this exact problem deploying .NET 4 and MVC 3 on IIS 6, thanks.

Comment: I also try according you but still no change.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue.  Strangely, for me it would run in integrated mode but not in classic mode for .NET 4.  After enabling the .NET 4 extensions via the Isapi and Cgi restrictions section in IIS 7, it then began working in both modes.  The Isapi and Cgi restrictions section is located at the server level node in IIS manager.  This option should not be confused with the Isapi Filters section at the site level.