# Invalid application path

Tags: iis-7

IIS7 Windows 7 64bit

No matter what I do I can't seem to add an application to a web site.

When I 'Test settings' I get "Invalid application path".

Any one have a guess as to what I could be doing wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Show us some more details. Add a screen shot!!!

Comment: I'm having the same issue: Open IIS, select an existing web application, goto "Basic Settings", click the button "Test Settings", see the error. 

I don't think a screen shot of the error message would be any more helpful. Though, this may not be the best place to post this question. 

Try http://serverfault.com

Comment: please take a look at this question & answer, I believe it will be helpful for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665578/404-2-error-after-installing-net-4-0

Comment: Probably right answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8826772/1193727

Answer (score 49):

When I got this error it appeared to be due to a security setting. When I changed the "Connect As" property to an administrator then I no longer got the message.

Obviously this isn't a good solution for a production environment - one should probably grant the least privileges necessary for the user IIS is going to be using by default. I'll update this answer if I learn more.

Comment: The error message itself might be a bug (see my answer) - "Connect As" may not be necessary

Comment: Turns out the message is just a bug. It works with an admin account because that account has all the permissions to all web directories. If you add your Network user to the Administrator you will not get this error also, without using Connect As

Answer (score 27):

The error message might be a bug.  I ignored it and everything worked for me.

[image: IIS Invalid Application Path Screen Shot]

See Here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1177952.aspx

and here http://forums.iis.net/p/1182820/2000936.aspx

Answer (score 10):

I eventually tracked this down to the Anonymous Authentication Credentials.  I don't know what had changed, because this application used to work, but anyway, this is what I did:
Click on the Application -> Authentication.  Make sure Anonymous Authentication is enabled (it was, in my case), but also click on Edit... and change the anonymous user identity to "Application pool identity" not "Specific user".  Making this change worked for me.

Regards.

Comment: This didn't work for me - but turning off Anonymous access and permitting Windows only authentication did the trick. Then turning off Windows authentication and turning on Anonymous did work as well. Very odd.

Answer (score 9):

Go to your HTTP bindings in IIS (select your website, then on the right click on Bindings...).
Delete your SSL and your HTTP binding. Re-Add them.

This usually fixes this for me.

Comment: This fixed the issue immediately. (Another typical, absurdly useless error message with a non-obvious fix.)

Answer (score 5):

Try : Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager -> Default Web Site -> Click Error Pages properties and select Detail errors

Comment: The detailed error led me in the right direction.  
**WCF - Error 500.21 Handler "svc-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list"**  
Solved with  `aspnet_regiis -iru // From x64 .net framework directory`

Comment: I did not encounter the WCF error but the aspnet_regiis command solved the issue for me as well. I started with a fresh setup of app pools and applications in the IIS as well.

Answer (score 4):

Problem was installing iis manager after .net framework aspnet_regiis had run. Run run aspnet_regiis from x64 .net framework directory

```
aspnet_regiis -iru // From x64 .net framework directory
```

[IIS Manager can't configure .NET Compilation on .NET 4 Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738559/iis-manager-cant-configure-net-compilation-on-net-4-applications#3738651)

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting this error, I found that it was because I had deleted the Default Application Pool "**DefaultAppPool**". Re-creating it fixed the problem. Drove me crazy for a few days.

This error will appear if either the web application is mapped to a non-existent app-pool; *or* if that application pool is stopped.

Comment: Equally this can happen if the assigned app pool is stopped.

Comment: Richard if that's an answer then make it a separate answer instead of a comment on this one.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this error.

My **IIS Website** has a **Default Website** with three (3) application directories below it.

I had each of my 3 application directories configured correctly to use .NET Framework v2.0 in the Application Pools.

[image: Edit Application Pool]

However, the **Default Website** never was configured. I didn't think it was necessary since all of my apps were contained within it.

My IIS Server's default configuration is .NET Framework v4.0, so I changed that to .NET v2.0:

[image: Edit Default App Pool]

After I did that, I no longer received the same error message.

Now, I see this:

[image: Result]

I hope this information helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting this error.  The problem for me turned out to be that I had two separate websites on the machine, and I had not designated which address went to which website. To resolve this, go to IIS Manager -> Select Web Site -> Bindings -> Add... -> Enter the host name that you want to resolve for this website.   Repeat for any other websites on the machine.

HTH.  Rick

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue today. It was caused by skype! A recent update to skype had re-enabled port 80 and 443 as alternatives to incoming connections.

H/T : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/549157/unableplustoplusstartplusdebuggingplusonplustheplu

To disable, go to skype > options > Advanced > Connections  and **uncheck** *"Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives to incoming connections"*

Answer (score 0):

I still haven’t find a solution, but find a workaround.

You can manually change IIS configuration, in system32\intsrv\config\applicationHost.config. Just manually create (copy-paste) section in `<sites>` and `<location>`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  (btw its not recommended.)

For my test app , I created a new application pool and changed its Identity to **"NetworkService"** .

[image]

More about App Pool Identities here
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities
and
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

You have to make sure that "NetworkService" has rights on your application's physical path.

Answer (score 0):

even it was getting the above error. i found out that IIS was not registered on the server.

registering the iis fixed the issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had virtual dir. When I accessed main WCF Service in main dir it was working fine but accessing WCF service in virtual dir was throwing an error.
I had following code in web.config for both main and virtual dir.

```
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <denyQueryStringSequences>
                <add sequence=".." />
            </denyQueryStringSequences>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

by removing from web.config in virtual dir it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the flaw by changing the file below:

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

In:

```
<application path="/" applicationPool="ASP.NET v4.0">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server" />
</application>
<application path="/Bonobo.Git.Server" applicationPool="ASP.NET v4.0">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server" />
</application>
```

For:

```
<application path="/">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\" />
</application>
<application path="/Bonobo.Git.Server" applicationPool="ASP.NET v4.0">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server" />
</application>
```